# ToString() Error: You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell

The Code:

```
$lastnumber = get-childitem "c:\temp" | % { $_.Name } | sort LastWriteTime | select -last 1 

$lastnumbertxt.ToString($lastnumber)
```

The Function `ToString()` produces the error:

> "You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression."

With `Write-host` I can check, that `$lastnumber` has a filename. And `$lastnumbertxt` does not. I want the filename as a string.

What is the Problem?

Comment: Where is the `$lastnumbertxt` variable being declare? running your code exactly as is will result in a Null value expression error since `$lastnumbertext` doesn't exist and is therefore NULL

Comment: I think what you want is: `$lastnumbertxt = $lastnumber.ToString()`

Comment: Thank you Esau. Exact that is the solution.

B.t.w. what do you mean with "declare"`? IMO that is not necessary like old school Basic with "Let" or "Dim".